# Libraray .h file not being connected with C++ Program

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I am trying to Create and Use a Static Library using the official examples

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

but i find that the cpp program can not get connected with the class definitions in the Library's .h file.

I get the error message: "........is not a class or namespace everywhere?"

Could you help me with this?
this is the c file:

```
#include "MathFuncsLib.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Subtract(double a, double b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    double MyMathFuncs::Divide(double a, double b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

This is the h file:

```
#pragma once
namespace MathFuncs
{
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public:
        // Returns a + b
        static double Add(double a, double b);

        // Returns a - b
        static double Subtract(double a, double b);

        // Returns a * b
        static double Multiply(double a, double b);

        // Returns a / b
        static double Divide(double a, double b);
    };
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error message(s)?

Comment: what are the names of your files, and are they both imported/created in the same project?

Comment: static or not??

Comment: There's no point in using a class to simulate a namespace.

Comment: `stdafx.h` must be the 1st `#include` in any file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you created your project, you did not switch off precompiled headers in Application Wizard.
[image]

That is why you get `#include "stdafx.h"` inluded and get a bunch of errors like that:
[image]

Tutorials say that you should disable it. Or you can just put `#include "stdafx.h"` first in your include list and it will compile.